# How to kill all processes owned by `user` on Centos 7?

Tags: process, process-management, pkill

I read in an online flash card that the command is:

```
pkill -u bob $(pgrep -u bob)
```

However, I think this is wrong. I think it's saying:

> Kill all the processed owned by `bob`, and `4572\n4600`

Because:

```
[bob@localhost ~]$ pgrep -u bob
4572
4600
```

Also, it gives an error:

```
[bob@localhost ~]$ pkill -u bob $(pgrep -u bob)
pkill: only one pattern can be provided
Try `pkill --help' for more information.
```

Which makes sense because you can't have newlines in usernames, right?

I think the command should only be:

```
pkill -u bob
```

To "kill all processes owned by bob"

While the command:

```
pgreg -u bob
```

Gives "all processes owned by bob"

I'm wondering:

- Am I uses the right commands as intended?
- Is my analysis of the incorrect way accurate?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### You Are Correct

Wrong:   `pkill -u bob $(pgrep -u bob)`

Correct: `pkill -u bob`

---

The flash card probably meant to show:

`kill $(pgrep -u bob)`

which would kill all of the processes returned by `pgrep -u bob`.

Comment: alternatively, `killall -u bob`.

Comment: Not relevant on CentOS, but if you're ever on a Solaris machine, `killall` on there really just kills all processes, no patterns or anything.